# Conditionally remove special characters from a string while being typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to attach a function to a form field so that - preferably as the user is typing into the field - special characters that I specify will be stripped out of the typed text. There are some conditions, however:

- Opening & closing parentheses are allowed
- Spaces are allowed, unless it's a trailing space at the end or two spaces in a row

I've found several examples of how to replace special or non-word characters from the string after the fact, but none so far on how to just strip out the characters I don't want, or how to remove spaces ONLY when it's a trailing space.

Note that I'm not married to JavaScript vs. jQuery (or vice versa), but it needs to be one or the other. I'm also not married to doing it on the fly, but that's the preferable option - some other functions already occur on the next field, so I'd rather have the proper value before the user tabs out of this particular text box.

I've attempted to use multiple replaces like the example below but it doesn't seem to like replacing a character with nothing (""). I'm also not sure how to write the condition for the trailing space.

```
var s1 = "I live on Hopper St.";
var s2 = s1.replace(/\./g, "");
```

This is primarily intended to auto-correct the three main problems we see:

- User enters a road name or abbreviation WITH period (St.)
- User accidentally hits space twice, resulting in a double-space
- User accidentally hits space at end, resulting in a trailing space

These values are used in a lengthy business process, passing the value to other fields, creating folders, etc. so things like periods, double-spaces, and trailing spaces all gum up the works later on. I'm trying to head those issues off at the pass by killing them in the first field.

Comment: What is you attempted code?

Comment: This is problematic. I may want to write `foo bar`, which is allowed. But if once I have written `foo ` you remove the trailing space, at the end I will have `foobar`.

Comment: Agree with @Oriol, you *can* do this if you want, but it's a horrible user experience. If a user presses a key they expect something to happen. They don't expect what they typed to suddenly disappear without explanation.

Comment: Regarding the spacing, I don't see why you wouldn't just enforce that on the back end.  A simple trim() will eliminate trailing white space and you can just use str_replace('.  ', '. ', $string).  I'm assuming PHP here, but it can be done similarly in many other languages.

Comment: @Ixalmida I may have to before I'm done. As it is, when the user tabs out of the field, the system does an automatic lookup from a database that populates other fields. I would have to figure out a way to intercept that lookup value between the focus change & the pass-through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly answering your question using the example you provided:

```
var s2 = s1.replace(/\s{2,}|\.|\s$/g, "");
```

This will remove any sequence of two or more white spaces, any dot, and any trailing space. The three parts of the pattern expression are separated by `|` (`OR`), so multiple calls to `remove` are avoided. You can also add a condition for a leading white space in the form of `^\s`.

However, this approach is risky, because:

1. Doing it on the fly will make users think something is wrong with your application (just imagine yourself as a user, you may think at first something is wrong with your keyboard). You could leave alone the text input and display the normalized value in a label nearby *after* the input loses focus.
2. This type of cleanup/sanitization/normalization should always be doubled on whatever backend you use. Client validation can be bypassed in so many ways. It's less important what the user sees in a text field, but more important what you actually save and use in the *lengthy business process* you mentioned.

So, do a proper client-side validation for the users, and a proper server-side validation for you.

Comment: This may work for my needs - I'll try it and see. I agree with you - normally I would do this sort of thing behind the scenes, but in addition to the intercept, the business unit has specifically requested that it happen while they type. We'll see if it stays that way once they have it. :-)

Comment: It looks like SharePoint is already appending an "onKeypress" function to the field when the page renders. Mine isn't working, so I'm guessing the other function is overriding it.

Comment: Perhaps you can unbind the onkeypress event and then attach your own, or use the onkeyup event as a workaround.

Comment: Ok - I found a way to append it to the process instead of as they type. So now it corrects what they typed, then puts the correct value into the field before continuing. Works beautifully for the periods and trailing space issue, but I need to replace the double-space with a single space instead of removing it. I'm guessing that will need to be a separate function, though? Either way, answer accepted - it got me started in the right direction!

Comment: FYI - I ended up passing my variable through a second line that replaced more than one space with a single space. Works great - thank you!

Comment: Cool. Yes, one way is to chain up another call to something like `.replace(/\s{2,}/, " ")`. Glad it worked.